# wildcard query expansion resulted in too many terms error

Tags: oracle10g

I am receiving a *wildcard query expansion resulted in too many terms* error when executing a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE contains(clob_field, '%WIN%') > 0 and rownum<=100;
```

there are more than `50000 rows` data in that query but this query has not run.

Does anyone know a workaround/solution to this problem?